# Plotly performance when updating many charts

Tags: javascript, python, plotly

I'm trying to build a real-time dashboard utilising Python/Flask and Plotly JS. I've set up a web socket (SocketIO) to pump data to plotly and am updating the plot data based on this. What I'd like to achieve is real-time plotting at >5 Hz (can sort of bin the point into batches every 200 ms).

The problem is that it currently seems to completely cripple my browser when I do this with more than ~5 plots. Please see below what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Plot Dashboard]

I have set it up in JS as follows: (9x)

```
<script>
                    Plotly.plot('X_AXIS',
                                [{x:[0],
                                  y:[0],
                                  type:'scatter'}],
                                {
                                    width: document.getElementById("col").offsetWidth,
                                    height:0.33 * document.getElementById("DataContent").offsetHeight,
                                    plot_bgcolor:"white",
                                    paper_bgcolor:("#ecc060"),
                                    margin:{l:15,r:15,t:30,b:30},
                                    xaxis: {range:[0,100]},
                                    yaxis: {range:[-10,10]},
                                    title: {text:'X-Axis'}
                                }
                                );
                </script>
```

With a function to update the data using updateTraces:

```
socket.on('UpdateTelemetry',function(Data){
        Plotly.extendTraces('X_AXIS',{x:[[Data[0][0]]],y:[[Data[0][1]]]},[0],100);
        Plotly.extendTraces('Y_AXIS',{x:[[Data[1][0]]],y:[[Data[1][1]]]},[0],100);
        Plotly.extendTraces('Z_AXIS',{x:[[Data[2][0]]],y:[[Data[2][1]]]},[0],100);
        Plotly.extendTraces('X_AXIS2',{x:[[Data[0][0]]],y:[[Data[0][1]]]},[0],100);
        Plotly.extendTraces('Y_AXIS2',{x:[[Data[1][0]]],y:[[Data[1][1]]]},[0],100);
        Plotly.extendTraces('Z_AXIS2',{x:[[Data[2][0]]],y:[[Data[2][1]]]},[0],100);
        Plotly.extendTraces('X_AXIS3',{x:[[Data[0][0]]],y:[[Data[0][1]]]},[0],100);
        Plotly.extendTraces('Y_AXIS3',{x:[[Data[1][0]]],y:[[Data[1][1]]]},[0],100);
        Plotly.extendTraces('Z_AXIS3',{x:[[Data[2][0]]],y:[[Data[2][1]]]},[0],100);


    });
```

I have tried going to scattergl, but honestly performance seems worse than just scatter. It seems like plotly is just hogging all the CPU time the browser gets for JS code, meaning the rest of the page becomes almost completely unresponsive. (can't even open dropdown menus anymore)

Is there any more performant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying something very similar and noticed the same limitations of Plotly. I think the reason is that when you do `extendTraces` you are redrawing each plot sequentially, it's not batched into a single render (https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_api.js#L935-L939). There is however a way to call `extendTraces` only once for all traces at the same time, which seems to be far more performant (see https://plotly.com/javascript/streaming/#streaming-subplots and https://codepen.io/federicomassa/pen/bGqGNeK). The relevant difference here is that, compared to your code, I am only calling `extendTraces` once, which I believe batches the redraw in a single rendering iteration.

If you already knew of this solution and thought that it didn't apply for your case because you have asynchronous data incoming for each plot, the solution I have pursued is to choose a refresh rate (say 25 Hz), and gather all data arriving between two iterations into a data store, that you can later query during each refresh iteration. You could even store the data into a simple structure like a Javascript object, such as:

```json
{
  data: {
    measure1: [
      { 
        timestamp: ...,
        value: ...
      }, ...
    ],
    measure2: ...
  }
}
```

Now, during each refresh you can call `extendTraces` only once with all the new measurements for each subplot.